# How To update Spring version in spring microservice

Tags: spring-boot, version, spring-cloud

i am trying to update my spring version to 2.7.3 for my existing spring microservice project but

Your project setup is incompatible with our requirements due to following reasons:

- Spring Boot [2.7.3] is not compatible with this Spring Cloud release train

Action:

Consider applying the following actions:

- Change Spring Boot version to one of the following versions [2.4.x, 2.5.x] .
  You can find the latest Spring Boot versions here [https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#learn].
  If you want to learn more about the Spring Cloud Release train compatibility, you can visit this page [https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#overview] and check the [Release Trains] section.
  If you want to disable this check, just set the property [spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false]

i updated spring cloud version to the latest one but then it throws cloud hystrix  version compatibility issue can some one explain how to update spring verison for existing  spring boot micro service project.

Thanks.

Comment: as it mentioned in log, you can use `spring.cloud.compatibility-verifier.enabled=false` and retry or you can down to `2.7.2` version and check for which compatible version hystrix is with that.

Comment: thanks ... i have managed to update that.